# Como usar las funciones de agregación de MySQL con valores de la misma fila

Tags: mysql

En MySQL existen algunas funciones estadísticas utilizadas como funciones de agregación (usadas con GROUP BY). Por ejemplo AVG (media) o STD (desviación estándar) se pueden usar para reducir múltiples columnas a un solo resultado.

Mi pregunta es: ¿No pueden usarse con campos de una misma fila? Por ejemplo, tengo la linea estudiante con las columnas score_1, score_2 y score_3. Si quiero la media o la desviación estandar de esos tres campos para cada estudiante (no quiero la media de todos los score_1, sino la media de los tres campos para cada linea de la tabla), ¿de verdad no puede ser realizado con un simple AVG(score_1, score_2, score_3) o algo similar?

Cuesta creer que algo tan simple no pueda ser hecho sin hacer un cross join con la misma tabla. Idóneamente,m querría crear una columna virtual que directamente calculara dichas estadísticas para cada fila cuando éstas fueran actualizadas.

Gracias por adelantado!

Comment: Gracias @Adrian, he editado la pregunta para ponerla en español.

Comment: Las funciones de agregación están pensadas para operar con los datos de un conjunto de registros. Para los datos de un único registro te sirve cualquier función o directamente los operadores aritméticos.

Comment: El problema parte en pensar que una tabla que tiene score_1 score_x es correcta, cuando en realidad estas violando tercera forma normal de los datos. y por eso no te deja calcular sobre si mismo, porque esta pensado para grupos de registros normalizados. Si vos queres calcular eso mismo sobre la fila, deberas hacer las cuentas a mano...

Comment: Gracias @DavidJP efectivamente eso es justo lo que quiero evitar, tener que usar operadores aritméticos para hacer, pro ejemplo, la desviación típica, cuando MySQL ya tiene una función que la realiza pero como función de agregación.

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi en realidad sí está en 3FN, porque los tres scores son independientes entre sí y se rellenan siempre, no aceptan el valor null. Es como si tuviera las columnas nombre y apellido en la misma tabla, no necesito separarlas en otra tabla para que estén en 3FN, Dicho esto, es verdad que diseñar la tabla como indicas, permitiría realizar la función de agrupación, pero precisamente la pregunta es cómo hacerlo con la estructura de una tabla. Lo que me cuesta entender es que no pueda usar una función que ya existe en MySQL para algo que no es agrupar.

Comment: No esta en tercera forma normal... que pasa si tuvieras 10 scores? O 2? Que sean independientes y admitan nulls no quiere decir que esten normalizados. Y no, las funciones de agregacion van sobre filas, no sobre columans, pq los datos deberian estat en distintas filas.

Comment: La tabla tiene tres y sólo tres scores. Y que conceptualmente son independientes entre ellos. Si tengo un usuario con apellido_1 y apellido_2, ¿tengo que crear una tabla apellidos para que esté normalizada? La normalización tiene que ver con la estructura real de lo que se modela, no con el nombre de las columnas. Pero la pregunta no es sobre normalización, por lo que la respuesta es lo que pones al final de tu comentario, que no se puede en la misma fila. Gracias por tus respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La repuesta corta a tu pregunta es que esa función que buscas no existe, ni falta que le hace :)

Me explico: así como para las funciones de totales, de agrupamientos o que operan por columnas, como `MAX()` o `MIN()`, existen las análogas por filas, o registro a registro, `GREATEST()` o `LEAST()`. Para `SUM()` o `AVG()` no tenemos su "equivalente" por filas.

¿Por qué? Pues mejor pregúntate: ¿Para qué?

Para las funciones de totales o por columna, únicamente les tienes que pasar como parámetro el campo que tienen que recorrer. En cambio, para las funciones que operan por filas, tienes que indicarles TODOS los campos sobre los que hacer el cálculo y eso puedes hacerlo perfectamente con los operadores aritméticos que quieres evitar.

Fíjate en que apenas hay diferencia entre:

```
SELECT AVG_FILAS(score_1,score_2,score_3) FROM tabla;
```

Y

```
SELECT (score_1+score_2+score_3)/3 FROM tabla;
```

En cambio, para `MAX()` y `MIN()`, ya sería algo más complicado, por eso para esos casos sí que está hecho.

En cualquier caso, con `CREATE FUNCTION` te puedes crear cualquier función a medida y tampoco descartes normalizar tu tabla, como ya te han comentado.

Espero haber respondido a tu inquietud y te agradezco que lo hayas compartido con nosotros. A veces aceptamos las cosas por costumbre y no está de más pararse a observar estos pequeños detalles que son los que permiten mejorar...

Comment: Está respuesta es la correcta, no se puede. El problema es que la función AVG, por seguir tu ejemplo, tiene en cuenta los null. Hacerlo con operadores no sería tan simple como pones. Y eso que estamos hablando de AVG. Con desviación estándar u otras funciones estadísticas más complejas, sería mucho más tedioso. Por eso preguntaba, para ver si existía la forma y es que yo no la conocía... Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si, con `IFNULL()` no es suficiente (para la media sí que serviría), siempre puedes contar nulos en una función un poco más compleja que tú definas...  [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)